# Python Django how to share a foreign key?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

In models.py, when I define a unique key on a model and then call it by another model under different variable names, it will not add those columns to the Sqlite table. Please, how to solve?

In my case, I want to define unique locations (location_id), then define movements between those locations (location_from, location_to).

This is my code:

```
# models.py
class Locations(models.Model):
    location_id = models.CharField(max_length = 10, unique=true)

class Movements(models.Model):
    blabla = models.CharField(max_length = 10, unique=true)
    location_id = models.ForeignKey(Locations, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='location_from')
    location_id = models.ForeignKey(Locations, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='location_to')
```

After makemigrations and migrate, the table Movements in db.sqlite3 does not contain the fields location_from and location_to.

What happened? My language is clearly wrong. Please, how to make it right?

Comment: You have two times `location_id` as field name... `true` is also not the keyword for `True`. You are (likely) obfuscating too much to enable people to debug this.

Comment: Don't call a field in a Django model `x_id`. Just call it `x`. `instance.x` returns the  instance of the class (table row)  to which the ForeignKey refers. The '_id` suffix is "magic" for use when you want to derive the integer value of a Django object's pk from the object itself, and `x_id_id` will confuse the heck out of everybody!

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the possible errors in your code.

```
# models.py
class Locations(models.Model):
    location_id = models.CharField(max_length = 10, unique=true)

class Movements(models.Model):
    blabla = models.CharField(max_length = 10, unique=True)
    location_from = models.ForeignKey(Locations, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='location_from')
    location_to = models.ForeignKey(Locations, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='location_to')
```

Comment: Hi @Lucas Moreira, 
Thank you. It adds the fields to the database but, in your code, how to make sure it will allow only Locations.location_id values?
For instance, consider there could be more parameters under the Locations model so, how to make sure location_from and location_to would pick from the right source?